# I need to find the total number of nodes of a tree in java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I will receive something like:

```
public int count (Tree myTree){
}
```

I already have the Tree definition, `getLeft()`, `getRight()` methods.

I have seen some examples, but always they receive a node as parameter, I need to receive the `Tree` as parameter.

Could anyone please help me? I'm new on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the tree have a method to get its root? That would be sufficient node to start with... What kind of `Tree` is it?

Comment: Node also has getLeft(), getRight() methods, Dont confuse between Tree and Node. Node represents Tree itself already

Answer (score 1):

Here Tree is the node class itself, meaning the name is given differently.
So myTree parameter is a node itself of the given Binary Tree, here pointing to the root in the given function.

[image: Binary Tree]

Now **Tree** and the **node** class itself in the picture **below**, where the right child and left child and the data of the current node are stored.

[image]

So to find out the number of nodes of a given tree,

You have to first check if the given *myTree* is null or not, meaning if the given myTree doesn't have any Root node only.
Then you have to return 0.

```
int count(Tree myTree)  
{  
    if (myTree == null)  
    return 0;  

    int res = 0;  
    if (myTree.left != null && myTree.right != null)  
    res++;  

    res += (count(myTree.left) + count(myTree.right));  
    return res;  
}
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 1):

A tree in fact is defined by its root node, but let's just say you implemented the Tree in your own way :p and that you have a function to get the root `getRoot()`, you can use recursion as it follows to count the number of nodes in your tree (we assume that for a node you can access the children with `getLeft()` and `getRight()`, you have to implement a function to construct a tree from a node `constructTree(Node root)`):

```
public int count (Tree myTree){
   Node root = myTree.getRoot();
   return root != null ?
     1 + count(constructTree(root.getLeft()) + 
     count(contructTree(root.getRight()))
     : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here  in `count (Tree myTree){ }`

`Tree` is the Node class only and you'll receive root node as a parameter which here is `myTree`

Because without root node it is impossible to access tree.
And in java Collections there is no such thing as `Tree`. So rest assured you are on right track.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Tree == Node as you have described your problem, then one approach is to use recursion:

```
public static int count(Tree tree) {
    Tree left = tree.getLeft();
    Tree right = tree.getRight();
    return 1 + 
        (left != null ? count(left) : 0) + 
        (right != null ? count(right) : 0);
}
```